# Automate HP Procruve Switch using PLink and echo

Tags: putty, plink

I'm trying to automate enabling\disabling ports on a HP ProCurve 2510G-24 switch using Putty\Plink in the command prompt in Windows. Ultimately I want to be able to run a scheduled task to run the batch file which enable\disable any port on the switch.

I've managed to run across the following to get this done: -Putty\Plink -Manually setting "tty=none" on the switch -using the echo command

Using plink with the -batch and -ssh flags, tty=none, and the first echo with at least a "space"/any character gets me logged in and past the "Press any key to continue..." prompt non-interactively. (THIS IS SOMETHING I've found out we've all had trouble with!!!)

The second command shown is theoretically what would work, but my output is "'interface' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

The -m value apparently doesn't work with passing the commands from the text file to the HP, it appears that Plink can start a shell when the -m flag isn't used, and when -N/-s is used it hangs.

The third is what should work but doesn't seem to be able to pass the commands: config interface 2 enable

````
C:\Windows\system32>echo /config| plink.exe -batch -ssh admin@192.168.1.2 -pw 12345678 -v 
Looking up host "192.168.1.2" for SSH connection 
Connecting to 192.168.1.2 port 22 
We claim version: SSH-2.0-PuTTY_Release_0.73 
Remote version: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_3.7.1p2 
 Using username "admin". 
Sent password 
Access granted 
Opening main session channel 
Opened main channel 
Allocated pty 
Started a shell/command

ProCurve J9279A Switch 2510G-24 Software revision Y.11.12

Copyright (C) 1991-2009 Hewlett-Packard Co. All Rights Reserved.

                       RESTRICTED RIGHTS LEGEND
Use, duplication, or disclosure by the Government is subject to restrictions as set forth in subdivision (b) (3) (ii) of the Rights in Technical Data and Computer Software clause at 52.227-7013.

     HEWLETT-PACKARD COMPANY, 3000 Hanover St., Palo Alto, CA 94303
Press any key to continue

tty=none DC PC SW 2510G24 1# config

tty=none DC PC SW 2510G24 1(config)#

C:\Windows\system32>echo.config && interface 16| plink.exe -batch -ssh admin@192.168.1.2 -pw 12345678 
config
'interface' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.```


C:\Windows\system32>plink.exe -batch -ssh admin@192.168.1.2 -pw 12345678 [-N/-s] -m c:\scripts.[txt/bat]
````